# Jenkins a node erases variables on an other node

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing

I have a problem with Jenkins. I have tests which are executed on Windows, RHEL7 and RHEL8 in parallel on 3 differents nodes. But the windows node modifies informations, variables on the RHEL8 node ( windows never modify the RHEL7 node ). If i run Windows with RHEL7 all it's ok, same with RHEL7 and RHEL8. But RHEL8 with windows failed.

For example:

```
def Valid(){
  myFile = load "Jenkins/myFile.groovy"
  ...
}


stage('Valid parallel')
{
  parallel (
    ('PROCESS RHEL7'):
    {
      node(rhel7_node) 
      {
        Valid()
      }
    },
     ('PROCESS windows'):
    {
      node(win_node) 
      {
        Valid()
      }
    },
    ('PROCESS RHEL8'):
    {
      node(rhel8_node) 
      {
        Valid()
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Then i have the following error on the RHEL8 node :

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\ProgramData...\Jenkins\myFile.groovy
```

So the windows path (C:\ ...) has erased the RHEL8 path on this node. When i comment parts of code i can see other local variables in the function Valid() which are erased by windows.